# How to correctly import tkinter module on Spyder? Python 3.9.6 related

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, conda, spyder

I want to create a python executable file with tkinter module, so far this is the code I have typed:

```
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import geometry, title, BooleanVar, set, Button
from tkinter import filedialog

import subprocess

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x400')
root.title("Bulk upload to OpenSea")
```

I know that tkinter module doesn't come by default on Spyder environment, so before compiling the program above, I [watched this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7Njb3xO4Fw) , then installed miniconda, and then did all the necesary steps explained in that video to allow importing the tkinter module, I also changed the default environment to `C:\Users\ResetStoreX\miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\python.exe` which is the `PATH` in which I installed the tkinter module with anaconda prompt.

Unfortunately, after compiling the program above with the necessary steps done, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\ResetStoreX\bulk masive\untitled0.py", line 9, in 
> from tkinter import geometry, title, BooleanVar, set, Button
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'geometry' from 'tkinter'
> (C:\Users\ResetStoreX\miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py)

May I know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geometry` and `title` is a method of tkinter window and toplevels, it is neither a class nor a file you can import. And `set` is part of python `builtins`. You prolly need just one type of `tkinter` import:

```
import tkinter as tk # OR from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import subprocess

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x400')
root.title("Bulk upload to OpenSea")
```

Now if you want classes, like `BooleanVar` or `Button`, you'd say `tk.BooleanVar` and so on... Or if you want files from `tkinter` package, you'd say `from tkinter import filedialog` and so on...

Comment: I think it worked! (No errors after compiling it) But I'm not seeing any window with 500x400 as resolution, what statement is left in order to see the window of this program?

Comment: @NoahVerner Usually, `root.mainloop()` at the end.